# Understanding Computational Complexity in Bitonic Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, complexity-theory, algebra

I am taking a parallel programming class and am really struggling with understanding some of the computational complexity calculations and algebraic simplifications.Specifically for the bitonic sort algorithm I am looking when each processor is given a block of elements.

I am looking at situations when either a hypercube or 2D mesh interconnection network is used. I am given the following definitions for the calculation of Speedup, Efficiency, Iso-Efficiency and determining if the solution is cost optimal. I can understand how Speedup is determined but am totally lost as to how to solve for Efficiency and Iso-Efficiency. I think I understand cost-optimality as well. Given below are the equations.

[image: bitonic sort equations]

The text which I am using for the class is

> [Introduction to Parallel Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201648652), 2nd Edition by Ananth Grama, Anshul Gupta, George Karypis & Vipin Kumar

For my question regarding the algebra of this problem, please refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604665/question-understanding-simple-algebra-with-regards-to-computational-complexity)